# How to use static class variable as initialization value for static class variable of other class with AMD in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, amd

please consider the following code, consisting of 3 simple classes, where I try to use a static class variable of a "common" class to initialize a static class variable of two other classes (to make sure they both use the same value).
I'm using AMD in my project settings as module system.

Here is the first class:

```
import TestClassCommon from "TestClassCommon";

class TestClass1
{
    static ParameterNames =
    {
        CommonName: TestClassCommon.ParameterNames.CommonName,
        TestClass1Name: "TestClass1Name"
    }

    SomeAction()
    {
        console.log("TestClass1 action");
    }
}

export default TestClass1;
```

Here the second one:

```
import TestClassCommon from "TestClassCommon";

class TestClass2
{
    static ParameterNames =
    {
        CommonName: TestClassCommon.ParameterNames.CommonName,
        TestClass2Name: "TestClass2Name"
    }

    SomeAction()
    {
        console.log("TestClass2 action");
    }
}

export default TestClass2;
```

And the "common" one:

```
import TestClass1 from "TestClass1";
import TestClass2 from "TestClass2";

class TestClassCommon
{
    static ParameterNames =
    {
        CommonName: "CommonName"
    }

    static DoSomething()
    {
        console.log("Common name =     " + this.ParameterNames.CommonName);
        console.log("TestClass1 name = " + TestClass1.ParameterNames.TestClass1Name);
        console.log("TestClass2 name = " + TestClass2.ParameterNames.TestClass2Name);
    }
}

export default TestClassCommon;
```

When I then use the 2 classes like this:

```
import TestClass1 from "TestClass1";
import TestClass2 from "TestClass2";

let tc1 = new TestClass1();
let tc2 = new TestClass2();
```

I get an exception in TestClass2:

> Unhandled exception at line 11, column 5 in
>   http://localhost:54375/scripts/TestClass2.js
>
> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property
>   'ParameterNames' of undefined or null reference

I ran into a similar issue some time ago, but after some advice from other people switched to using the above way of importing, defining the classes and export the classes, and that solved the issues.

But now I ran into this issue again.
Can anyone get this simple example to work?
Thanks!

Comment: You can't import `TestClass1` and `TestClass2`  in `TestClassCommon` and at the same time import `TestClassCommon` in both `TestClass1` and `TestClass2`. Can you avoid using `TestClass1` and `TestClass2` inside `TestClassCommon`?

Comment: As @lujcon pointed out your problem here is circular dependency. `TestClassCommon`'s name suggests that it contains shared stuff so it shouldn't reference `TestClass1` and `TestClass2`.

Comment: This is a simple case, constructed for example purposes.
In the real case, there are more classes involved.
I could rewrite a bunch of them to extract certain parts into yet another class, and try to eliminate using circular dependencies, but I was trying to avoid that...
It does happen from time to time that one class needs something from another one, and in languages like C++ or C# there are no problems with circular dependencies, so I was hoping TypeScript with AMD also had a way to handle this properly.